# PostgreSQL Table Multiple Values

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I am working in postgreSQL and I want to create a table and in one column of this table I want to have multiple values as booleans. For example:

```
create table if not exists x(
     Numx numeric(5) PRIMARY KEY,
     method (here for example I want method to be able to be something like this "method {a,b,c,d}"
);
```

So method could have either value a or b or a,b etc.

How am I able to do so?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use an array type.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    name            text,
    pay_by_quarter  integer[],
    schedule        text[][]
);
```

You can see loads of examples in the docs. I personally would only use them if I had hundreds that I wanted to store, for a few booleans I'd likely use a column each or a bitmask.